# Dynamically generated Class instances

Tags: python, class

I want to store values that I plan to later use for sorting pdfs on my computer using PyPDF2. 
I thought that if I created a class and stored identifying info for each type of file (such as a descriptor, a string that is unique to the file and can be found by PyPDF2 later such as an account number, and the path where the file should be moved to) that would work. Something like this:

```
class File_Sort(object):
def __init__(self, identifier, file_text, file_path):
    self.identifier = identifier
    self.file_text = file_text
    self.file_path = file_path
```

so an example input from me would be:

```
filetype0001 = File_Sort("Phone Bill", "123456", "/Users/Me/PhoneBills/")
```

I would like to be able to have users generate new file types via a series of raw_input questions, but I can't figure how to generate the variable to create a new instance, so that I can get:

filetype000[automatically incrementing number] = File_Sort(UserResponse1, UserResponse3, UserResponse3).

Creating the "filetype000[automatically incrementing number]" text itself seems easy enough with:

```
file_number += 1
file_name = "filetype" + str(file_number).zfill(4)
```

but how do you turn the generated file_name string into a variable and populate it?

Comment: you can alway's use `@classmethod` to generate an instance of your class using some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to dynamically create variables. That's almost always a foolish thing to do. Instead, you should be using a data structure like a list or dictionary, indexed by the parts of the variable name you wanted to generate dynamically.

So instead of creating a list named `filetype000`, start with a list named `filetypes`, and append an inner list, so you can do `filetypes[0]` to get at it. Or if string names make more sense for your specific application, let `filetypes` be a dictionary, and access the inner lists with something like `filetypes['pdf']`.

I'm being a little vague here because I don't really understand all of your pseudocode. It's not at all obvious what the purpose of the `[automatically incrementing number]` parts of your example are, so I'm more or less ignoring those bits. You probably just want to start with an empty list and `append` values to it, rather than somehow initializing it to a specific size and magically indexing it.

Comment: Yes, I'd earlier looked at using dictionaries as they seemed the obvious choice (and at that stage I only had a limited awareness of classes), but couldn't figure how to associate more than one value with each key. I gather you can store tuples as values, which would allow me to do what I want, but I couldn't figure how to store the tuples or only one out of the two values in the tuple.

Comment: So you would suggest that I create three lists, one with identifiers, one with the file text, and the last with the file path, and then just use the same index location in each list to store the three associated values? So that I could output by using: print("file_name%s, %s ,%s, %s" % (file_number, identifier[file_number], file_text[file_number], file_location[file_number]).

Answer (score 0):

so fyi this is what I ended up using:

```
file_descriptor = []
file_string = []
file_location = []

filetype_new = len(file_descriptor)

input_descriptor = raw_input("What is the description of the new file type? ")
file_descriptor.append(input_descriptor)
input_filestring = raw_input("What is unique string to search for in this file type? ")
file_string.append(input_filestring)
input_filelocation = raw_input("where should we put this file type? ")
file_location.append(input_filelocation)

print("file%s: %s, \t%s, \t%s" % (str(filetype_new+1).zfill(4), file_descriptor[filetype_new], file_string[filetype_new], file_location[filetype_new]))

review = raw_input("\nWould you like to review the current files? y/n ").lower()
while review not in "yn":
    review = raw_input("Sorry, I don't understand. Would you like to review your file types? y/n ").lower()
print("There are currently sort instructions for %s filetypes: " %  (len(file_descriptor)))
file_increment = 0
while file_increment in range(0, len(file_descriptor)):
    print("file%s: %s, \t%s, \t%s" % (
    str(file_increment + 1).zfill(4), file_descriptor[file_increment], file_string[file_increment],
    file_location[file_increment]))
    file_increment += 1
```

thanks for your advice.